# Counting values accordingly to conditions, but in blocks of 3 rows

Tags: r

I have an R data frame:

```
a <-1:6
x <- c(0.2,3.7,4.6,1.1,2.2,5.3)
df1 <- data.frame(a,x)

df1
  a   x
1 1  0.2
2 2  3.7
3 3  4.6
4 4  1.1
5 5  2.2
6 6  5.3
```

I would like to compute how many times the value in "x" is >3.2. However I want to calculate it for groups of 3 rows. So for example I group the rows in "block1" (rows 1,2,3) and "block 2" (rows 4,5,6), and I want to know how many times "x" value is >3.2 in each block rather than in the singular rows, obtaining something like:

```
block  count
 1      2 
 2      1
```

In my original data I have much more entries, so ideally I need a command to create consecutive blocks of 3 rows, instead of creating the blocks manually.

Can you advice how to compute this? I have been suggested to use *plyr*, but I have not been successful.

I hope this is clear enough.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
> df1 %>% 
    mutate(block = rep(1:2, each=3) %>% factor) %>% 
    group_by(block) %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(x>3.2))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  block count
  <fct> <int>
1 1         2
2 2         1
```

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake... I edited your answer sorry for that I just thought to edit my answer. I rolled back now.

Comment: Minor FYI, you can define a new variable in `group_by` (and it doesn't need to be a factor), simplifying to `group_by(block = rep(1:2, each = 3))`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Gregor!

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(block = as.integer(gl(n(), 3, n()))) %>% 
  group_by(block) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(x>3.2))
```

```
  block count
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
data.frame(block = 1:(length(x)/3), count = rowSums(matrix(df1$x, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) > 3.2))
#>   block count
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     1
```

UPDATE: Using a wide matrix is somewhat faster:

```
data.frame(block = 1:(length(x)/3), count = colSums(matrix(df1$x, nrow = 3) > 3.2))
#>   block count
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     1

x <- runif(6e5, 0, 5)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(byrow = data.frame(block = 1:(length(x)/3), count = rowSums(matrix(x, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) > 3.2)),
                               bycol = data.frame(block = 1:(length(x)/3), count = colSums(matrix(x, nrow = 3) > 3.2)))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#>  byrow 5.121082 5.410939 9.250643 7.526198 10.409384 69.91496   100
#>  bycol 3.280639 3.539040 5.536414 5.320978  6.279585 12.38163   100
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(cbind(count = x>3.2)~cbind(block = ceiling(seq_along(a)/3)),df1,sum)
  block count
1     1     2
2     2     1
```